# Gwan kv, persistent flag / Number of items

Tags: c, key-value, ram, g-wan

I have decided to use Gwan's KV store in place of a Redis NoSQL database. I saw in the Manual that the kv supports a persistent flag for file IO to keep data I guess between restarts. It uses the callback recfn, but how exactly would this function be formatted to save the KV to a file, I understand C file IO just not quite interfacing this call back and formatting the data to a file, and then the reverse of reloading it back into the KV when Gwan starts.

Also I noticed you can set the number of items that the kv will have. How can this be set so that there is technically no limit, so things can be continuously added untill you run out of ram

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recfn` callback is user-defined and allows you to decide under which format data will be stored on disk (plain-text, formated, indexed, compressed, distributed, etc.).

We recognize a dedicated example would surely help, thanks for pointing that.

The number of items that you can indicate at the creation of a key-value store is merely an hint aimed to using appropriate memory allocation strategies - it does not actually limit the size of an ever-growing store.

Comment: given that it's been 2 years since the answer, is there any code example for `recfn` yet? Even the simplest kind of example wil do. Also as of now it's not clear how g-wan might reconstruct the kv data from disk after a server restart.

Comment: Since then we refocused on the reason why G-WAN was written in the first place: our Global-WAN.com Cloud and this explains why no new public release was made available.

Comment: You mean nobody have access to this feature of G-WAN, even the registered users?

Comment: There are dozens of minor and major features that have not been published - even at the time G-WAN releases were publicly published. That's because G-WAN as a freeware app server was one thing, and G-WAN as the basis of our Global-WAN.com Cloud infrastructure was another thing aimed at internal use only. From time to time, we get demands for custom-works and we then either use what was already written or we add specific features for specific needs.